# What is the meaning of 噂に翻弄させられる?

Tags: passive-voice, causation

A character in this visual novel being subjected to threats and rumors has this inner monologue:

> 脅迫状の言いなりにさせられて､今度は**噂に翻弄させられて**

I understand the basic usage of させられる to be "made to do something", like 悪魔に毒リンゴを食べさせられる would be "made to eat a poisonous apple by a demon", where に indicates who caused you to eat the apple. For my question, I think the に would indicate the character was being toyed with by these rumors if it had been written **翻弄されて**, but 翻弄させられて instead makes me unsure because I understand it as meaning the character was being made to toy with someone else due to the rumors, which I don't understand in the context of the story.

Is there another understanding of 噂に翻弄させられる here?

Comment: Maybe whoever wrote that (mistakenly) thought 翻弄する was an intransitive verb.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simply a mistake. As you understand, it should  be 翻弄されて.

As the (existence of) following website suggests, it happens reasonably often

> [source](https://precious.jp/articles/-/36478#:%7E:text=%E3%80%90%E3%80%8C%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%80%8C%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AF%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%EF%BC%9F%20%E3%80%8C%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%95%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E5%8F%97%E3%81%91%E8%BA%AB%E3%81%A7%E4%BD%BF%E3%82%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%8C%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84%E8%A8%80%E8%91%89%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8C%E3%80%81%E3%80%8C%E7%B4%A0%E6%97%A9%E3%81%84%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8D%E3%81%A7%E7%9B%B8%E6%89%8B%E3%82%92%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AB%E3%80%81,%E3%80%8C%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%A8%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%82%82%E9%96%93%E9%81%95%E3%81%84%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AF%E3%81%82%E3%82%8A%E3%81%BE%E3%81%9B%E3%82%93%E3%80%82%20%E3%81%9F%E3%81%A0%E3%81%97%E3%80%81%E3%80%8C%E7%BF%BB%E5%BC%84%E3%81%95%E3%81%9B%E3%82%89%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%80%8D%E3%81%AF%E8%AA%A4%E7%94%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%80%82)
>
> ただし、「翻弄させられる」は誤用です。